# How many Screens should i use?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I've learned the Java basics, and now I'm trying to create something with LibGdx. I want to create a very simple game so I can learn by doing.

I don't really have a vision on how the game will exactly look at the end, but this exercise is more like "Hey, a new idea, I'll try 
to make this!"

The gamescreen will be split into 3 parts.  For the upper and lower parts I have 2 draw-methods in the render-method of my `Screenclass`.

Down on the screen there will always be a menubar. I have released this with a simple backgroundimage and a inputprocessor. It has 5 buttons.

Every time when I click on one of these a "Button" will appear the middle of the screen to do something complete different. For example,  if I click on Button 1, then there's a list of something.  When i click on button 2, then there's a minigame and so on.

How should I develop this? In my mind was the idea to do all this in methods in render, with a if-wrapper who will be true when I click the button. Is this the "right" way to do?  Or should I be making a lot of different screens?

Anyway, on some of the middle-screens I want something similar:  a menu and a list of things and buttons, so when I click on the menu the list and buttons will change but I don't know how to create this.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Try to mock it out with a pencil on a paper and see if the flow works. See if the "flow flaws". There´ll be as much or as less screens as needed and no one can assure you a correct answer for that: Some people loves details in a popup and some in a full screen window with photos and wistles...

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I wasn sure because in many tutorials and examples theres only 1 screen for the titlemenu and 1 screen for the game itself, so i thougt i do something wrong when i make so many screens.Is there some better resolution for the changes in the middle in the same "menu-field" or can i simply do many screens too, without any negative effect i have to fear?

Comment: I'm going to have to agree with @eduyayo . Jumping into code is more fun, but the development phase needs to include planning. Your question is almost a software engineering question rather than a coding question. You should plan out all of your features.  Decide what classes you'll need and then decide what methods make sense for each of the classes. Then based on your organization decide what you want on each screen & their appearance. Right now your question is very subjective as it can be done in many different ways.  Design first, code second, repeat ad nauseam. Good luck & welcome to SO!

Comment: Thanks for the nice welcome and the usefull help :)